# How to capture all HTTP requests from certain processes?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, http, monitoring

I've searched for this, I came to know *WinPCap*, but I still didn't get the answer I needed.
*WinPCap* can monitor packets, and seems not to give a track to processes (I don't know much about it).

**I want my application to listen to every HTTP request made from certain processes (usually the ones from browsers which I will define later), and modify them if necessary.**

My application is originally written in *Delphi*, but any help in *C++* would also be cool.
Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit 1**: Of course I don't expect you to give me an answer according to *winPcap* necessarily!

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can't know which process the packet is from, once it is at the WinPCap level - it is a driver product that picks up each packet as it goes in or out of the machine. At that point, which process it came from is "lost".

Comment: I hate it when some guys vote for closing the question when they just don't know the answer!! What is wrong with this question?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Maybe *WinPCap* can't do that, I'm looking for any library that might be helpful.

Comment: Since you mention Delphi, I'm assuming this is for Windows. In that case, you can probably do the job with the [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463267.aspx) (but it will *not* be trivial).

Comment: Can you describe what you actually want to do? The problem is a generic packet sniffer (such as WinPCap) is at a network layer where "which process" doesn't matter. And most network analysing tools follow this principle. To know which process is sending what packets, you'd need to be at the application side of the OS, which pretty much means "hooking into the process".

Comment: Writing an HTTP proxy may be the simplest solution, depending on your problem parameters.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: *WFP* has come with `Windows Vista`! Am I wrong?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: "Hooking into the process". Maybe that leads me to what I'm looking for. How can I hook process HTTP requests?

Comment: @Javid: Yes, WFP is new in Vista. If you need to support XP, you probably want to look at the WinSock [Service provider Interface](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0599/LayeredService/LayeredService.aspx).

Comment: Can you please describe what you are looking to do, instead of asking for solutions to an anonymous problem. Note that hooking is a bad thing, and will often upset antivirus software, so unless you get onto the "good list" from the AV software guys, your application will be low on the list "we recommend this".

Comment: And why is it only CERTAIN http request you care about? Surely if you want to, say, stop porn or intercept traffic to sites that are anti-christian, or whatever it is you happen to be trying to do, it shouldn't really matter which process the requests are from?

Comment: Look, I'm developing a download manager. So I need to capture downloads from browsers. I know I can do this by writing extension for each browser, but I'm looking for a more general way. (*IDM* has done the exact thing I'm looking for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ideas I can think of, depending on how low-level you need to get and other parameters of your requirements

- Set up an HTTP proxy of some kind.  This could be something you write yourself and configure the browser to use.  Or it could be something like Fiddler - I'm not sure if Fiddler allows you to plug in your own functionality...if not and if it's open source, then you can do whatever you like.
- Look into existing browser plug-in mechanisms.  For example for IE there are BHOs (Browser Helper Objects).  TBH I'm not sure what exactly the various plug-in mechanisms allow.  If you get native code executing in the browser, maybe you can hook arbitrary APIs (see Detours below)
- Use the MS [user-level hooking mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to inject code (a .dll) into the target processes.  You can configure the hook to only load into processes with a certain name (e.g. iexplore.exe) and maybe other attributes as well.  Worst-case, you can hook all processes and then in your DllLoad bail out if the process is not one you want to hook.  In your hook's DllLoad, use an entry-point hooking mechanism like [Detours](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/&ei=rz0FUvCFB8_YigKl_4DIBA&usg=AFQjCNEzgL4U1FWOVvfg-QeA0_yjJU_aTA&sig2=mAors1abIuaU94T2YYn-UQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.cGE) to hook a set of network APIs with your own functions.  Then whenever the process calls those network APIs it will be the function in your DLL that is called.  It can do whatever it wants (e.g. modify the data being sent) and then call through to the real method.  For example, IE uses WinHTTP (I think) which uses wininet which uses winsock.  I have done this (not for networking but other APIs) many times and the mechanism itself is straightforward.
- Write a network driver of some kind to filter all traffic.  Without thinking through the details right now, you should be able to figure out what process the traffic is for even from kernel mode.  I can't remember exactly but I think Window's (which is to say, NT's) network stack has user-mode drivers as well.

Lots of software like VPNs have to do what you are talking about.  It's definitely possible, including per-process filtering.  One thing to always keep in mind, if you have control of the OS you want to do this on (Administrator rights), you can do anything you want.  Unlike certain mobile OSes, in desktop OSes you own the OS and the hardware and don't have to beg permission to do what you want with your own property. It's only a matter of how hard it is and how long it will take...

Answer (score 5):

WinPCap allows you to access the source and destination IP/Port pairs for each captured packet.  You can iterate the OS's TCP tables (on Windows, you can use [`GetTcpTable2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx) and [`GetTcp6Table2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405.aspx)) looking for those pairs, and when you find a match then you will know the process ID that owns that connection.  From that ID, you can then extract further information about that process from the OS (filename, etc).

Comment: The most annoying problem WinPCap has, is that it has problems with WiFi connections. For example, it can't recognize my internet connection. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try SnoopSpy3 application.
http://www.snoopspy.com/778
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this will help the asker? It seems she ask for a programmatically way to listen and edit packets.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows I've used Sysinternals ProcMon to achieve this filtering by the PID and then Tools -> Network Summary

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon